How to prove that $A_{n-k}=\lim\limits_{x\to a}\frac{d^k}{dx^k}(f(x)(x-a)^n)$?
I randomly came across the following formula related to partial fractions:
If $f(x) = \frac{P(x)}{Q(x)} $ is a rational function, and $ Q(x) $ has a root $ (x-a) $ with multiplicity $ n $, then the coefficient of the term $ \frac{1}{(x-a)^{n-k}} $ in the partial fraction decomposition of $ \frac{P(x)}{(x-a)^n} A_{n-k}$ is given by:
$$A_{n-k} = \frac{1}{k!} \lim_{x \to a} \frac{d^k}{dx^k} \left[ f(x) (x-a)^n \right], \quad k = 0, 1, \dots, n-1.$$
This formula appears very interesting, but I have been struggling to prove it.  often get stuck when trying to compute partial fractions involving repeated roots and create a mess after finding $A_n$ like this, I was surprised to see a formula like this exist since I tried to come up with a one many times but failed. I wasn't successful in proving this formula

This is basically using Taylor's theorem, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition#The_role_of_the_Taylor_polynomial. Let me know if you'd like more details.

Let's assume that $f(x) = \frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$ with $\operatorname{deg}(P) < \operatorname{deg}(Q)$ and $P(a) \neq 0$. Now, partial fraction decomposition tells you that
$$f(x) = \frac{P(x)}{(x-a)^nq(x)} = \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{A_i}{(x-a)^i} + r(x) \text{ where } q(a) \neq 0 \text{ and } |r(a)| < \infty$$
Multiply this by $(x-a)^n$ and do an index shift in the sum:
$$(x-a)^nf(x) = \sum_{i=1}^nA_i(x-a)^{n-i} + (x-a)^nr(x)\stackrel{i = n-k}{=}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}A_{n-k}(x-a)^{k} + (x-a)^nr(x)$$
Differentiating this gives you the formula searched for.
